# How to get HTTP response without using the HTTP library in Golang?

Tags: go, systems-programming

I am trying to learn systems programming. I was wondering how I could place a GET request for a URL without using any libraries like HTTP for the same. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your are basically asking on how to implement  the HTTP protocol, which is a very broad question. There are actual standards for this, see RFC 7230 for HTTP/1.1. Which means you need to read the documentation in order to understand the protocol and then you need to implement this protocol on top of sockets. If you want to implement HTTPS without libraries too you also need to implement TLS yourself - which is even more complex than HTTP. To get an idea just have a look at the existing implementation of the protocol in Go, these are all open source.

Comment: You want to create an HTTP client by yourself from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

It's surprisingly easy if you're using sockets directly; HTTP is a very simple protocol. Here's an HTTP GET (with HTTP 1.1) to a given host at port 80:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    s := os.Args[1]
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", u.Host+":80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rt := fmt.Sprintf("GET %v HTTP/1.1\r\n", u.Path)
    rt += fmt.Sprintf("Host: %v\r\n", u.Host)
    rt += fmt.Sprintf("Connection: close\r\n")
    rt += fmt.Sprintf("\r\n")

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(rt))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(resp))

    conn.Close()
}
```

That said, the whole HTTP protocol has many different options and variants and takes a lot of time, effort and tuning to implement.

---

The Go source code is fairly approachable usually, so you could read the code of `net/http`. There are also alternative HTTP packages implemented using lower layers, like https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How do I get the error code or the response code from the whole response and even just the HTML? Is there a way to get this other than normal text parsing?

Comment: @AdityaGaikwad: you just parse it from the first line in the response

Comment: Thanks a lot again!
If I use -
var buf bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(&buf, conn)

and then check length of buf, it is not the same as length of resp. Could you tell me why that could be? And which would be the better or more accurate reading of number of bytes of response?

Comment: @AdityaGaikwad: I'm not sure which code you're referring to, but this sounds like a completely separate question. `io.Copy` and `ioutil.ReadAll` both read until EOF, the difference is just how the data is returned / where it's written.